# How to access the value stored in variable of angular service from another component

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-routing, angular-services

I want to share the question details along with option array from one component to another using services. How do i need to store the value & get that value from the service

my question-**service** class ---

```
private static  ques_optn : Array<QnA>;
constructor() { }

public setQuestion(qna :Array<QnA>) : void
{
 qna.forEach(element => { QuestionService.ques_optn.push(element)});

}

public getQuestion() : Array<QnA>
{
return QuestionService.ques_optn;

}
```

my **login.ts** class setting the value to the variable ---

```
 {
      ques_ans: Array<QnA> = [];
      this.ques_ans;      (conatins the value)
      this.questservice.setQuestion(this.ques_ans);
    }
    my question.ts class for retrieving  the value ---

    this.ques = <QnA[]>this.questservice.getQuestion();
```

I want to get the values in "this.ques" variable in question.ts class

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it seems that you intend to use the service as a data repository... But you can't store value in a service;

If a component uses a service, it is injected (and instantiated) into it and therefore is blank of any data that is contained in it. It won't maintain data which you intend to centrally use in your different components.

Comment: then sir how to do it, can you plz tell some method

Comment: structure of Angular encourages us to create a component for a specific function, if same data is needed by different components, you can pass data to child components and access using @Input in the child component

Comment: but they are  siblings component sir.